# Cannot find service 'ALTabletService' in index

Tags: tablet, nao-robot, pepper, choregraphe

I'm having a problem with the tablet of Pepper. I am trying to display the index.html to the tablet using the `show app` box. I made only at the Application one `show app` box to the `root` diagram.

An error occurs when I run the application:

> [ERROR] behavior.box: _getTabletService: 24  _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehavior544669552: / init_8 / Show App_2:
>   Can not find service 'ALTabletService' in index

In addition, I also get the following awarning:

> [WARN] behavior.box: onInput_onStart: 45   _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehavior544669552: / init_8 / Show App_2:
>   Could not find tablet service, so can not set application: .lastUploadedChoregrapheBehavior

Development environment is as follows.

- Model name: MacBook Pro
- OS: El Capitan 10.11.5
- Processor name: Intel Core i5 2.6 GHz
- Memory: 16 GB
- Graphics: Intel Iris 1536MB
- Choreographe: 2.4.3.28
- Pepper: 2.4.3.28

Answer please.

Comment: Are you connected to a real Pepper or the simulated one ?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you are connected to the real Pepper and not to the virtual robot (as the virtual robot does not include the ALTabletService).

Answer (score 1):

From experience (Nao) the error would suggest that the module is not available. I don't have the luxury to get my hands on a Pepper yet, but if your are not using a virtual robot, I would fire up a python session and try:

```
from naoqi import ALTabletService
```

and see if that goes through. If not, it would mean that there is problem with your SDK installation or env. path. If it goes through, it would be robot issue. Again you NEED TO make sure you are "connected" to a real Pepper, not a virtual robot in Choregraphe, in order for "Show App" to work.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out ALTabletService is only available on a real robot (as it runs inside the tablet).
Also sadly this service is not the most stable service on the robot, and it might from time to time be missing (it will restart automatically). So you might need to protect your application against this (by waiting for it, ignoring errors, exiting, ... depending on your workflow).